# Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName' ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I looked everywhere and I can't figure out what the problem is with my asp project.

Basically I get this error

> Invalid object name dbo.Enquires.

It's looking for a table which doesn't exist, and I never mention that table anywhere, not sure why it's looking for it.

**EnquireController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Net;
using PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models;



namespace PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Controllers
{
public class EnquireController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin, Mod")]
    // Enquire
    public ActionResult Index(string SearchName)
    {
        var items = from i in db.Enquiries select i;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchName))
        {
            items = items.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(SearchName));
        }
        return View(items);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles ="Admin, Mod")]

    // Details
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        }
        Enquire enquire = db.Enquiries.Find(id);
        if (enquire == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(enquire);
    }

    // Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Post Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create ([Bind(Include ="Id,Name,Address,Suburb,State,Postcode,Email,Phone,Description")] Enquire enquire)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Enquiries.Add(enquire);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["message"] = "Your enquiry has been successufully submitted.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(enquire);
    }

    // Edit

    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Enquire enquire = db.Enquiries.Find(id);
        if (enquire == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(enquire);
    }


    //Post edit

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include =       "Id,Name,Address,Suburb,State,Postcode,Email,Phone,Description")] Enquire enquire)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Enquiries.Add(enquire);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(enquire);
    }


    // Delete
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Enquire enquire = db.Enquiries.Find(id);
        if (enquire == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(enquire);
    }

    // Post Delete
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]

    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Enquire enquire = db.Enquiries.Find(id);
        db.Enquiries.Remove(enquire);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

   }
 }
```

**Enquire.cs Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models
{
   public class Enquire
   {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Suburb is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Suburb")]
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required")]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And that is The Page I get the error on.

```
@model IEnumerable<PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models.Enquire>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<div class="container">
<h2>Index</h2>


@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
}
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Mod"))
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p>
            Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchName")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Suburb)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Postcode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suburb)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Edit", new { id = item.Id}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }) 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error and I can't seem to fix it. I don't have much experience with asp.net. Here is the error I get http://pastebin.com/Gmmhn0VX

It keeps looking for dbo.Enquires and that doesn't exist, I also searched the whole project and I can't see anywhere that something refers to dbo.Enquires.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is the ApplicationDBContext

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Security.Claims;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
 using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

 namespace PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models
 {
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your     ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?  LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }



    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models.Price> Prices { get; set; }


    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PetePersonalTrainerFinal.Models.Enquire> Enquiries { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Post your ApplicationDbContext  class code as well

Comment: from your code `from i in db.Enquiries select i;` and many more places have reference to this table..

Comment: @Reddy Sorry, but am I missing something? I'm referring to db.Enquiries and it keeps searching for db.Enquires (its a typo)

Comment: @J.A - your code seems Ok. can you please check if it is returning any items in Action method ? Also what is name of table created in Db ?

Comment: The name of the table is Enquiries. and I get the error only when i add  @foreach (var item in Model) on the page. Also here are the exception details http://pastebin.com/pjM9X8PL Also how would I check if it returns items in Action method? I'm just starting asp so not sure. Thanks

Comment: this is model first approach right?

Comment: @J.A - try decorating Enquire Model class with [Table("Enquiries")]

Comment: Yes, this is model first.

Comment: @AjinderSingh is right

Comment: My god, yes. Thank you Ajinder, adding that fixed the problem. Thank you! I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: @J.A - Glad that it helped you. Btw i think it's Code First approach not Model First.

Comment: @AjinderSingh  yes it is Code first..

Comment: @AjinderSingh You can post the same as answer and deserved for the reputation.

Comment: @Arulkumar - It's Ok . J.A already posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Decorating `Enquire` Model class with `[Table("Enquiries")]` fixed the issue.

Credits to [Ajinder Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475831/invalid-object-name-dbo-tablename-asp?noredirect=1#comment62450216_37475831).